# avoiding text overflowing below images

Tags: graphics, floats

I have multiple images on a single page(there are 2-3 pages like these one after the other). I don't want the images to have any text below them other than the caption in each page.
However, the headings and texts of the next sections or previous sections are automatically getting adjusted below them.

Is there a way to modify the below code so that I can ensure that only the images occupy the sheet and nothing else?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[ht!]
     \begin{center}
%
        \subfigure[Caption of First Figure]{%
            \label{fig:first}
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{FirstFigure.png}
        }%
        \subfigure[Caption of Second Figure]{%
           \label{fig:second}
           \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{SecondFigure.png}
        }\\ %  ------- End of the first row ----------------------%
        \subfigure[Caption of Third Figure]{%
            \label{fig:third}
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{ThirdFigure.png}
        }%
        \subfigure[Caption of Fourth Figure]{%
            \label{fig:fourth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{FourthFigure.png}
        }%
%
    \end{center}
    \caption{%
        The l-o-n-g caption for all the subfigures
        (FirstFigure through FourthFigure) goes here.
     }%
   \label{fig:subfigures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

To add the section heading before the figure I modified the code below. But it doesn't work. Kindly help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\section{Heading-1}

\begin{figure}[hp]
     \begin{center}
%
        \subfigure[Caption of First Figure]{%
            \label{fig:first}
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{FirstFigure.png}
        }%
        \subfigure[Caption of Second Figure]{%
           \label{fig:second}
           \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{SecondFigure.png}
        }\\ %  ------- End of the first row ----------------------%
        \subfigure[Caption of Third Figure]{%
            \label{fig:third}
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{ThirdFigure.png}
        }%
        \subfigure[Caption of Fourth Figure]{%
            \label{fig:fourth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{FourthFigure.png}
        }%
%
    \end{center}
    \caption{%
   Subheading 1
     }%
   \label{fig:subfigures}
\end{figure}





\begin{figure}[p]
     \begin{center}
%
        \subfigure[Caption of First Figure]{%
            \label{fig:first}
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{FirstFigure.png}
        }%
        \subfigure[Caption of Second Figure]{%
           \label{fig:second}
           \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{SecondFigure.png}
        }\\ %  ------- End of the first row ----------------------%
        \subfigure[Caption of Third Figure]{%
            \label{fig:third}
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{ThirdFigure.png}
        }%
        \subfigure[Caption of Fourth Figure]{%
            \label{fig:fourth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{FourthFigure.png}
        }%
%
    \end{center}
    \caption{%
      Subheading 2.
     }%
   \label{fig:subfigures}
 \end{figure}


\section{Inference}
From the above figures we infer x y z



\section{Heading-2}

\begin{figure}[hp]
     \begin{center}
%
        \subfigure[Caption of First Figure]{%
            \label{fig:first}
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{FirstFigure.png}
        }%
        \subfigure[Caption of Second Figure]{%
           \label{fig:second}
           \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{SecondFigure.png}
        }\\ %  ------- End of the first row ----------------------%
        \subfigure[Caption of Third Figure]{%
            \label{fig:third}
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{ThirdFigure.png}
        }%
        \subfigure[Caption of Fourth Figure]{%
            \label{fig:fourth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{FourthFigure.png}
        }%
%
    \end{center}
    \caption{%
      subheading 3.
     }%
   \label{fig:subfigures}
\end{figure}





\begin{figure}[p]
     \begin{center}
%
        \subfigure[Caption of First Figure]{%
            \label{fig:first}
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{FirstFigure.png}
        }%
        \subfigure[Caption of Second Figure]{%
           \label{fig:second}
           \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{SecondFigure.png}
        }\\ %  ------- End of the first row ----------------------%
        \subfigure[Caption of Third Figure]{%
            \label{fig:third}
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{ThirdFigure.png}
        }%
        \subfigure[Caption of Fourth Figure]{%
            \label{fig:fourth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{FourthFigure.png}
        }%
%
    \end{center}
    \caption{%
        subheading 4.
     }%
   \label{fig:subfigures}
 \end{figure}

\section{Inference}
From the above figures we infer x y z


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More or less the only effect of using `ht` here `\begin{figure}[ht!]`  is to remove the option `p` which is by default allowed and means to put the float on a page on its own with no text. So delete `[ht!]` or to explicitly force that it goes on a float page use `[p]`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It worked. ! However, I would like to add the the \section{Results} to the first image, with [p] even the title is kicked out of the page. How can I modify the first image in my results sections so that the heading appears before it ?

Comment: @user157522 you haven't provided an example so this is untested but [hp] probably works

Comment: Thank you, it kind of worked but the heading of the next section also moved to the first figure :/ sorry to be a bother. I added the working example in the original code. I am just learning now. Kindly help.

Comment: use ,\clearpage before the next section